# div width in css

Tags: css, html, width

i have a div on a web page  that basically acts as a panel container.  i want it to:

1. have a minimum width of 1000px;  So no matter how small the content inside the div is, it will at least keep the panel to 1000px in width:
2. in terms of max width, it should keep going as big as the content within it.  So if a person has a 24 inch monitor and they want to maximize the browser it should keep growing until the content inside doesn't have any scroll bars and then stop.
3. needs to work in all browsers.

how would i do this in css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this item is a block element (i.e. "display: block"), it should scale automatically as wide as its containing element (in this case the browser window).

In CSS, just specify "min-width: 1000px." This will work in IE8+ and all modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#panel
{
   /* Other styles */
   min-width:1000px;
   /*width:100%; - removed as it will create horizontal scrollbar if margin and padding aren't 0 as per Josh's comment.*/
}
```

However, you will problems with older browsers like IE6 which do not like the `min-width` thingy in which case you will need to use JavaScript.

Comment: `width:100%` is superfluous.  Block level items always expand to 100% of their parent.

Comment: I would recommend against explicitly setting 100% width because browsers screw that up when you add things like margin and padding. Just setting display: block should handle this.

Comment: I don't know how the other bits of his CSS are. Maybe he overwrites the width somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#panel {
  min-width: 1000px;
  diplay: block;
  overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: why would i want overflow: hidden??

Comment: overflow hidden help full width our div full screen without scrolling if there is user screen resolution less then our width e.g 800px

Comment: Nice trick Anjum. However, he may want his users to be able to access the content that is overflowing. In that case he would need to have "overflow: auto".

Comment: @Josh 1. he don't want to scroll the contents, 2. 960px width is fine for ever