# resizing div width with browser resize

Tags: jquery, css, html, width

[i recently asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490605/div-width-in-css) on how to have a container div width set so i could avoid scrolling for folks with wide monitors.  I got a great answer basically to combine **min-width** with **display: block**;

I now have one follow up.  The accepted answer works great if the browser up front is set to be wide but if at first its not wide and a user stretchs the window, the div container doesn't change or stretch.

is there anyway i can take this one step further and reset the width of the div when the browser window itself resizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use absolute positioning,

```
#panel {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 50px;
 right: 50px;
 bottom: 50px;
 background: #eee;
 border: 3px double #000;
 overflow: auto;
 }


<div id="panel"><p>I shrink and grow</p></div>
```

`overflow:auto;` sets a scroll bar on the `#panel` itself if the content requires it.. which may not be desired?

#### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/2jE5s/)

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

How about estimating the area of screen, your page should cover and writing the width in percentage?

For example,

```
#wrapper { width: 90%; }
```

Comment: @ooo, for your question `resizing div width with browser resize`, using percentage based in best option AFAIK. Rather than relying on script and cross browser incompatible CSS.

Comment: @Downvoter, Please kindly explain the downvote and help me improve my answer.